# How to split two values in one textBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to split the values in one `textBox` using `/` as a separator?

Value format: `192.168.0.0/24`

Two `textBoxes` are currently used, and this is not convenient:

[image]

Comment: use string.Split extension method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `Split` method:

```
string str = "192.168.0.0/24";
var result = str.Split('/');
Console.WriteLine(result[0]); // ip
Console.WriteLine(result[1]); // mask
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/QTAX74494)

Comment: Thank! figured out thanks to your demo `result[0]` and `result[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way  is :

```
       string value = "192.168.0.0/24";
        Console.WriteLine(value.Split('/').First()); 
        Console.WriteLine(value.Split('/').Last());
```